# SquashFS image as rootfs in LXC

Tags: linux, boot, lxc, squashfs

Is it possible to use a SquashFS filesystem as an LXC rootfs? I can mount an ext3 image as a rootfs just by setting `lxc.rootfs` to the filename, but if it's any other type of image, `lxc-start` just says that it can't mount an ext3 filesystem. The `lxc.conf` man page doesn't suggest any way to specify the filesystem type.

Additionally, if I get past that stage, can you mount other loopback filesystems in the container just by using `lxc.mount.entry` entries with `'loop'` in the options field?

Answer (score 1):

I have a working setup with some squashfs containers, especially for security reasons

For starting, simply add

```
lxc.rootfs = loop:/var/lib/lxc/yourcontainer/rootfs.squashfs
```

to your config file.

Interestingly, I see dmesg messages like

```
[218687.113742] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[218687.118615] FAT-fs (loop0): invalid media value (0x00)
[218687.120368] FAT-fs (loop0): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

... which I cannot avoid because there is no `lxc.rootfs.type` option. But these messages are not errors - everything works as expected.

The rest are normal read-only-root problems: Files which the system wants to write to (like resolv.conf and logs). You might want to symlink them to a tmpfs volume.

I never tried to mount another squashfs to a sub-path of this container, but a normal bind mount of a host directory works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount as rootfs squashfs image, but it would be read-only.

```
mount: warning: /var/lib/lxc/busy2/rootfs/ seems to be mounted read-only.
```

You should have another layer over squashfs, e.g. [aufs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs).

This technique mass used in [Slax](http://www.slax.org).

You can repeat this just by hand. Make true lxc config, than mount your squashfs image to rootfs dir by aufs layer.

From [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/aufs.5.html) page:

```
# sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/rw_branch:/ro_branch none /aufs
```

My experiment with busybox return True:

```
# mount -o loop -t squashfs /var/busy/busy_rootfs.squashfs /var/busy/squashfs-mnt/
mount: warning: /var/busy/squashfs-mnt/ seems to be mounted read-only.
# mount -t aufs -o br:/var/busy/aufs-root/:/var/busy/squashfs-mnt/ none /var/lib/lxc/busy2/rootfs

# lxc-start --name busy2

udhcpc (v1.20.2) started
Sending discover...
Sending select for 10.0.3.105...
Lease of 10.0.3.105 obtained, lease time 3600

Please press Enter to activate this console.



BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/ # ls
ls
bin      etc      lib      mnt      root     selinux  usr
dev      home     lib64    proc     sbin     tmp      var

/ # touch root.file
touch root.file
/ # ls -latr root.file
ls -latr root.file
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Aug 23 12:38 root.file
```

Look from host:

```
# ls -latr /var/busy/aufs-root/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 23 12:15 var
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Aug 23 12:25 .wh..wh.plnk
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Aug 23 12:25 .wh..wh.orph
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 23 12:25 .wh..wh.aufs
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 23 12:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 23 12:38 dev
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 23 12:38 root.file
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 23 12:39 .
```